# merge arrays without same values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays:

```
$a = array('a','b','c');
$b = array('b','c','d','e');
```

What must I do in order to get array `('a','d','e')` via array `$a` and `$b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a = array('a','b','c');
$b = array('b','c','d','e');
$output = array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a));
```

I think that is right - is off top of my head.

Yup http://ideone.com/56V0d0 <- fiddle here - seems to work!